# Best way to access field in array of structs in Julia

Tags: julia

```
struct Point
   x :: Int
   y :: Int
end
```

If I have an array `a` of type `Array{Point}`, is there a better way (either syntactically cleaner or faster) to do field access than this?

```
(p->p.x).(a)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Four options are:

1) `(p->p.x).(a)`

2) `[ z.x for z in a ]`

3) `map(p->p.x, a)`

4) `getfield.(a, x)` (suggested by Michael in the comments)

The first 3 will be about as efficient as each other, so it comes down to personal preference. Method 4 is a bit slower on my machine, but as the other answerer (Gnimuc) states, this will hopefully be fixed up by issue #22710.

Note, I often also find the following method useful:

```
getx(a::Vector{Point}, inds=1:length(a))::Vector{Int} = [ a[i].x for i in inds ]
```

which allows you to pull out the `x` field for an arbitrary set of input indices. (although it will be slightly slower than the above 3 methods for pulling out every index). My metaprogramming sucks, but you can actually do something like this:

```
for fn in fieldnames(Point)
    eval(parse("get$(fn)(a::Vector{Point}, inds=1:length(a))::Vector{Int} = [ a[i].$(fn) for i in inds ]"))
end
```

which will get you the above `getx` function but for every fieldname in the input type...

Comment: Or `getfield.(a,x)`

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard Thanks. Added to answer.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard Do you mean the discussion in [#16285](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/16285)? I'm not sure what the status of that is at the moment...

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard Should it be `getfield.(a, :x)` on Julia `v"1.0.1"`? And on my macOS 10.14, Julia `v"1.0.1"`, the `getfield.(a, :x)` turns out to be the most efficient now.

Comment: umm, I believe on Julia 1.1.1 the most efficient way is getproperty.(a, :x) on a CentOS 6 node

Comment: `getproperty` as well, is similar to `getField`

Answer (score 5):

The cleanest way is to define your own operator which was originally posted by **@pabloferz** on Discourse: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/broadcast-over-getfield-in-0-6/2335/4

```
struct Point
   x :: Int
   y :: Int
end

a = [Point(i,j) for i = 1:10 for j = 1:10]

↦(val, s) = getfield(val, s)
a .↦ :x
a .↦ :y
```

### UPDATE:

For now, a quick benchmark shows `(p->p.x).(a)` is the fastest among other solutions if `a` is small. when the length of `a` grows large, both `map` and `comprehension` are slightly faster than `(p->p.x).(a)`:

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.6.0
Commit 903644385b* (2017-06-19 13:05 UTC)
......

julia> @btime (p->p.x).($a)
  88.283 ns (1 allocation: 896 bytes)

julia> @btime [ z.x for z in $a ]
  109.578 ns (2 allocations: 912 bytes)

julia> @btime map(p->p.x, $a)
  163.485 ns (3 allocations: 944 bytes)

julia> @btime getfield.($a,:x)
  1.586 μs (101 allocations: 4.00 KiB)

julia> a = [Point(i,j) for i = 1:100 for j = 1:100]

julia> @btime getfield.($a,:x);
  160.845 μs (10002 allocations: 390.70 KiB)

julia> @btime (p->p.x).($a);
  9.817 μs (2 allocations: 78.20 KiB)

julia> @btime map(p->p.x, $a);
  8.306 μs (3 allocations: 78.22 KiB)

julia> @btime [ z.x for z in $a ];
  8.306 μs (3 allocations: 78.22 KiB)
```

`getfield` is always 10~20x slower than other methods, so the cleanest way is not performant. But it seems that the situation is going to be improved in the future, we'll have a syntax sugar for this?: [`Make .a syntactic sugar for i->i.a #22710`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/22710).

Comment: Interestingly, I got `(p->p.x).(a)` to be the slowest of the three on my machine, although I used an input vector of length 1000, rather than a 10x10 matrix...

Comment: @ColinTBowers yes, I got the same result with a 100x100 array, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Gnimuc what is μμs?

Comment: @Liso ah, they're just `us`, fixed. I was copy-pasting from REPL on a Windows machine that doesn't correctly handle Latex symbols.

Answer (score 0):

As you also asked about a syntactically clean way. You can define the following function

```
function Base.getproperty(array::Array, field::Symbol)
    return getfield.(array, field)
end
```

This way, your access simply becomes `a.x`. This is the same behavior as seen in, e.g., Matlab.

Comment: I think it counts as type piracy since you "own" neither Base nor Array: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#Avoid-type-piracy