# Broadcast operator over field of an array of structures (Julia)

Tags: julia, broadcast

I have an array instantiated structures (of the same type). I would like to change the value of a certain field of these structures. For performance reasons I would like to avoid using a for loop. Here's a toy code to illustrate what I do:

```
mutable struct foo
    x
end

a,b = foo(5), foo(7)

arr = [a,b]

.-(getfield.(arr,:x),1)
```

I expected this to get the x fields into an array (of pointers to the actual x fields of the actual foo's) then apply -1 to all these.
When I call `a,b` they are unchanged. I know after debugging that this is because `broadcast()` of getfield materializes (`Broadcast.materialize`) the fields into a new array, i.e. it is copied.

Is there a proper and performant way to do this without loops ?

Thank you

Comment: Why not loops? They're just as fast (if not faster) and very straightforward.

Comment: I was told that vectorized expressions are faster. I can't remember where but there was some sort of demo with sum() being much slower than a vectorized expression. Is it not though ? I thought it was because broadcasting does less memory allocations or something (I'm an amateur so I could definitely be wrong).

Comment: This old post indeed says that they are supposed to be faster but it is not the case yet (in 0.6, I use 1.1). [Link](https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots)

Comment: And [this](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html#More-dots:-Fuse-vectorized-operations-1) advises to do so either, from julialang.org

Comment: I typically think of it in the following way. 1) loops in Julia are fast. 2) broadcasting in Julia is smart enough to be equivalently fast. Sometimes broadcasting can be faster than a badly written loop (e.g. when SIMD operations are possible), but in general a properly written loop is always fast.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Broadcasting is implemented with a simple `for` loop in Julia itself.  We "dogfood" our loops, so they absolutely have to be fast.  The blog post and documentation you link to don't compare broadcasting against an equivalent for-loop — they compare array operations against their fused counterparts.

Comment: In case you are not aware: if you are concerned about performance, you must put type annotations on the field members of your structs. And yes, loops are the default way to get great performance.

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820304/best-way-to-access-field-in-array-of-structs-in-julia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop should be fast, as [Matt B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176071/matt-b) has indicated. However, if you want to avoid loops (mostly for convenience reasons) you can write either:

```
foreach(v -> v.x -= 1, arr)
```

(which actually is a kind of loop, but I would not expect it to be faster than a loop)

or use [StructArrays.jl](https://github.com/piever/StructArrays.jl) which is excellent from my experience. What you want can be achieved e.g. like this (using your `arr`):

```
using StructArrays
arr2 = StructArray(arr)
arr2.x .-= 1
```

and StructArrays.jl takes care to subtract `1` from field `x` in all elements of `arr2`.

**EDIT** And you can expect `StructArray` to be sometimes faster if you perform column-wise operations in comparison to a `for` loop over collection of structs (in your example the field has type `Any` so this should be not relevant, but if it had e.g. type `Int` and the struct had many fields you could notice the difference).